# I can't see inside the container with a vnc

Tags: php, windows, docker

I have a script in php that raises an image of docker (havnesvo / slimerjs) and it passes a .js since the slimer needs a js to boot. When I expose the container and try to see inside with vnc send an error: The host refuse the connection. My script look like:

**bash**

```
SCRIPT="script.js"

docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/scripts havnesvo/slimerjs bash -c "sed -i 's/640x480x8/1600x1400x8/' /usr/bin/xvfb-run && /usr/bin/slimerjs /scripts/$SCRIPT"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I try to call the script in bash without php script: 'docker run --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/scripts havnesvo/slimerjs bash -c "sed -i 's/640x480x8/1600x1400x8/' /usr/bin/xvfb-run && /usr/bin/slimerjs /scripts/adv.slimer.js"' and nothing

Comment: What happens when you manually run the command in an interactive `bash`? It would be helpful if you showed any messages it printed.

Comment: Thank i resolve the problem with the routes, but now I cant see inside the container with a vnc